# Python script syntax error

Tags: csv, python-2.7, compare

My experience with Python is limited, so I've been using other StackOverflow questions/answers to guide my script, primarily this one: [Python: Comparing two CSV files and searching for similar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268929/python-comparing-two-csv-files-and-searching-for-similar-items) and this one: [How to Delete Rows CSV in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271331/how-to-delete-rows-csv-in-python)
I am attempting to match IDs from two separate csvs each of which looks roughly like:

```
ID trip  date     location
1   1    1/1/2009 384
1   2    1/3/2009 384
1   3    1/7/2009 467
2   1    1/2/2009 842
2   2    1/3/2009 362
```

I am trying to match based on the trips each ID takes, so for ID 1 in csv1 I look for all IDs in csv2 that have a trip on 1/1/2009 from location 384, then from that list I look for which ones also have a trip on 1/3/2009 from location 384 and so on until there is only one ID from csv2 that matches the ID in csv1: a match. Here is the code I have:

```
import csv, sys, fileinput

f1 = open('personal2009.csv', 'rb')
f2 = open('company2009.csv', 'rb')

c1 = csv.reader(f1)
c2 = csv.reader(f2)

vmslist = [row for row in c2]

matchDict = {}
ID_list = []
ID = 0
for log_row in c1:
    if log_row[0] != ID:
        ID = log_row[0] 
        matchlist = csv.writer(open("matchlist" + str(ID) + ".csv", "wb")
        for vms_row in vmslist:
            if vms_row[2] == log_row[2] and vms_row[3] == log_row[3]:
                matchlist.writerow(vms_row)
    elif log_row[0] in ID_list:
        continue
    else:
        f = fileinput.input("matchlist" + str(ID) + ".csv", inplace=True)
        w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
        for match_row in csv.reader(f):
            if match_row[2] == log_row[2] and match_row[3] == log_row[3]:
                w.writerow(row)
        if len(list(w)) == 1:
            matchDict[str(ID)] = match_row[0]
            vessel_list.append(str(ID))

f1.close()
f2.close()
matchlist.close()
```

Whenever I try to debug or run the code in PythonWin, I get the error **Failed to run script - syntax error - invalid syntax** in the footer of PythonWin and the cursor stops at the row: **for vms_row in vmslist:**
I get no further explanation or error information than that. I have tried renaming all my variables and nothing gets past this error, so I have to conclude I am trying to do something incredibly silly and I can't see what it is. Any thoughts?

Comment: There is a missing close-paren on the line above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
matchlist = csv.writer(open("matchlist" + str(ID) + ".csv", "wb")
#                -----^  --^ 2 opening                        --^ but one missing here.
```

Python cannot know that there is a parenthesis missing until the next line, where your `for` statement makes no sense as part of the `csv.writer()` call.

Answer (score 1):

This:

> matchlist = csv.writer(open("matchlist" + str(ID) + ".csv", "wb")

Should be this (you were missing a parenthesis at the end):

> matchlist = csv.writer(open("matchlist" + str(ID) + ".csv", "wb"))