# How to copy rows from one CSV to another CSV file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to copy rows from one CSV to another, and also to remove rows after being copied from the first file.

Please see the code, it is working for only copying specific rows from one CSV file to another, but it is not removing the rows from file 1.

```
import csv
import os

File1 = 'in.csv'
File2 = 'out.csv'

with open(File1, "r") as r, open(File2, "a") as w: 
     reader = csv.reader(r, lineterminator = "\n")
     writer = csv.writer(w, lineterminator = "\n")

     for counter,row in enumerate(reader):
         if counter<0: continue
         if counter>50:break
         writer.writerow(row)

with open(File1, "w") as r: 
     reader = csv.writer(r, lineterminator = "\n")

     for counter,row in enumerate(reader):
         if counter<0: continue
         if counter>50:break
         reader.writerow(row)
```

Please let me know how this would work after coping the rows to the File 2 and then remove those rows from File 1.

Here is the error:

```
for counter,row in enumerate(reader):
TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Delete Rows CSV in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271331/how-to-delete-rows-csv-in-python)

Comment: but this is not working can you solve this

Comment: please mention the error you getting while running this code? Also provide the sample data on which you working. Seems mostly data issue from the description

Comment: @Sarjan: What is not working? Did you read the answers on above linked question? `You can't remove rows from a file but you can rewrite it with only the ones you want.`

Comment: it's just coping rows from one csv file to another.. but I want to know how to remove the rows from file one.. Im just a beginner in python

Comment: the above answer is about to compare two csv not my solution s there

Comment: The solution *is* there. Read what @ChankeyPathak said; *You have to re-write the file without the rows that you want removed*

Comment: @Sarjan, Have a look at the `pandas` module. this will make your life much much easier. If you have a `pandas` question, there are tons of articles, tutorials, etc. If you get stuck the Pandas community here on Stack is pretty friendly

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to move the first 50 rows from one file and append them to another. This needs to be done in a few steps:

1. Read each of the 50 rows from `in.csv` and append each one to `out.csv`.
2. Write the remaining rows from `in.csv` to a temporary file.
3. Delete the original `in.csv` file and rename the temporary file to be `in.csv`.

For example:

```
import itertools
import csv
import os

file_in = 'in.csv'
file_out = 'out.csv'
file_temp = '_temp.csv'

with open(file_in, "r", newline='') as f_input, \
     open(file_out, "a", newline='') as f_output, \
     open(file_temp, "w", newline='') as f_temp:
    
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

    # Append first 50 rows to file_out
    csv.writer(f_output).writerows(itertools.islice(csv_input, 0, 50))

    # Write the remaining rows from file_in to file_temp
    csv.writer(f_temp).writerows(csv_input)

# Rename f_temp to file_in, first remove existing file_in then rename temp file
os.remove(file_in)
os.rename(file_temp, file_in)
```

This assumes you have a standard comma delimited file and that you are using Python 3.x.

Comment: it's slicing every character and appending. Not copying from delimiter

Comment: It assumes a standard CSV format with comma delimiters. The original script was also designed for Python 2.x, I have updated and tested it with Python 3.7.