# Python - Copy a row from a csv and paste it in another csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'd like to understand how to copy a row from a .csv file and paste it in another .csv.
Specifically, I have a large number of .csv files with the same column format. For each of these files, I should search for a **string** in a column and, if I find it, I have to append the corresponding row in **another csv file**.

E.g. --> **the string is "Bob"**

file1.csv

```
| First Name | Last Name | Age |
| Bob        | Arnald    | 22  |
| Alice      | Halton    | 25  |
| Tom        | Jackson   | 26  |
```

file2.csv

```
| First Name | Last Name | Age |
| Max        | Phoenix   | 33  |
| Bob        | Niall     | 23  |
| Sean       | Roger     | 26  |
```

The output file would be 
out.csv \

```
| First Name | Last Name | Age |
| Bob        | Arnald    | 22  |
| Bob        | Niall     | 23  |
```

I tried using csv library, but it's not clear how to isolate a single row and append it into another csv file.

Comment: So, you want to create a new csv file only with common name from both csv files?

Comment: I've just updated the question format (I think tables are more understandable now). My aim is to scan a specific column of each csv file (in the example, "First Name"). If I find a specific string in the column (in the example "Bob"), I want to copy the entire row corresponding the found string in the output csv file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy rows from one CSV to another CSV file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807864/how-to-copy-rows-from-one-csv-to-another-csv-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1 = df1[df1['First Name'] == 'Bob']
df2 = df2[df2['First Name'] == 'Bob']
combined = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Note - pd.concat can be used on a list of any amount, therefore you can create a function to filter a df and iterate it over all your dfs, adding them to a list and then concatenating it.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

Then when you get your dataframe of all combined rows

new_df.to_csv(filepath/filename.csv)